# $H=\{xy:x,y\in G\}$ is an open subset of R

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G$ be an open subset of $R$.

If $0\notin G$, then show that $H=\{xy:x,y\in G\}$ is an open subset of $R$.

Now Since $G$ is open , given $x,y\in R$, $\exists ,r_x,r_y$  such that $B(x,r_x)\subset G$
and $B(y,r_y)\subset G$.Now all we need to do is find a radius $r$ given a point $xy$ in $H$.

Not sure how that would work out. may be $min(r_x,r_y)$??

Comment: by $R$ you mean $\mathbb{R}$ right?? It would be better if you stick to usual notation... what do you say?

Comment: yeah of course..

Answer (score 5):

Prove first that if $c\ne 0$ the function
$$P_c:{\Bbb R}\longrightarrow{\Bbb R},\qquad P_c(x)=cx$$
is homeomorphism (is obviously continuous and $P_c^{-1}=\cdots$).

Then,  $H=\bigcup_{x\in G}P_x(G)$ is a union of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

Try $r=\max(|x|\cdot r_y,|y|\cdot r_x)$, it's relatively easy.

The optimal radius is $r=|x|\cdot r_y+|y|\cdot r_x-r_x\cdot r_y$.

I want to expand on optimality. For any open set $G\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $x\in G$ denote
$$r_{x,G}:=dist(x,\mathbb{R}\setminus G)$$
and for $x,y\in G$
$$r_{x,y,G}:=dist(x\cdot y,\mathbb{R}\setminus(G\cdot G)).$$

1. For any $G$ and $x,y\in G$ we have $r_{x,y,G}\ge|x|\cdot r_{y,G}+|y|\cdot r_{x,G}-r_{x,G}\cdot r_{y,G}$.
2. When $G$ is an interval the above becomes an equality if $x$ and $y$ are closest to the same endpoint, but for most sets and pairs the inequality is strict.
3. I don't know if there is a set such that the inequality is strict for all pairs. I'm leaning no.
4. Whether or not the conjecture in 3. holds, because of (2.)
   $$(x,y,a,b)\mapsto|x|\cdot b+|y|\cdot a-a\cdot b$$
   is the biggest function on $\mathbb{R}^2\times(\mathbb{R}^+)^2$such that (1.) holds when composed with
   $$(x,y,G)\mapsto(x,y,r_{x,G},r_{y,G}).$$